# Delete task on multiple remote servers

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I can run this command line to delete task on single remote server:
SCHTASKS /delete  /tn "testTask" /s (hostname) and it works perfect.

However I need to be able to do the same on multiple servers from one command line or batch file. I've tried using for loop option to run against the list of servers provided in text file and seems like it does not read that text file. Here is the example:

```
For /F %f in (c:\temp\testservers.txt) do schtasks /delete /tn "testTask"
```

it outputs this ERROR: The specified task name "testTask" does not exist in the system.. Its seems like it searching task on my laptop instead of on remote servers provided in .txt file. (task does exist on remote server)

I have used the same For loop command to create task on multiple servers with a bit different parameters and it works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply forgot to add your %f parameter after the Delete command, which doesn't use the same parameters as the Create command, as documented on [this MSDN page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/cc725744(v=ws.10).aspx#):

```
schtasks /delete /tn {<TaskName> | *} [/f] [/s <Computer> [/u [<Domain>\]<User> [/p <Password>]]]
```

So you should try :

```
For /F %f in (c:\temp\testservers.txt) do schtasks /delete /tn "testTask" /s %f
```

To log the results in a file, use something like:

```
For /F %f in (c:\temp\testservers.txt) do schtasks /delete /tn "testTask" /s %f >> C:\Mylogs\TaskDeletions.log
```

Comment: Thank you so much that did it. One other question if you don't mind, how can I save the status of each delete to a text file? Like "The scheduled task was successfully/unsuccessfully deleted from 'servername'". Something like that. Thank you so much I appreciate it.

Comment: @user3078287: simply add **>> C:\MyLogs\TaskDeletions.log** (or whatever you want the file to be named) at the very end of the line. I have edited the original response to reflect that.